# Can I use a free field team to upgrade an existing one?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

Some mission rewards grant a free field team. If I already have a level 1+ field team in all 9 districts, can I use that free field team to upgrade an existing team, or is it wasted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use that "1 free field team" for a free rank upgrade aswell as a free replace.

Comment: Agreed, I just used one from the Spec Ops project to upgrade a level 2 Technology team to level 3.